# How should I handle more or less related spam?

Tags: support

A new user has posted answers to old questions so far. Most of them refer to articles on a site called OnPath Testing. The answers are mostly relevant to the question, *but* the user has not disclosed her affiliation with the site.

This morning, I pointed out that if she is affiliated with the site, she needs to disclose this. Three hours later, she added another answer to an old question, again linking the site, and again failing to disclose or mention any affiliation to the site.

I searched, and found that she is indeed affiliated with the site, under a different name.

The user's profile: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/16571/ritu-dhillon
Profile on Sticky Minds: http://www.stickyminds.com/users/ritinder-kaur
Question by the user on Sticky Minds (the user link goes to the profile above): http://www.stickyminds.com/question/can-we-customize-data-types-software-testing

Once I realized that the user is not disclosing her affiliation I flagged some of her answers as spam - should I have done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did was perfect. I'm working on cleaning them (although it'll probably wait until lunch, fighting a fire with an app at work right now... stupid work...)

The only thing I would add would be a reference to the [Help article that deals with self promotion](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), specifically the last paragraph, that explains why you're flagging them.

It's worth mentioning that if they declare their affiliation, each individual post is accepted. And if that 'astroturfing' is what brings them to the site, that's okay. It's expected, though, that if they're going to continue to promote their product, even in situations where it's appropriate in every instance, that they are also contributing in ways that don't promote their product.